# Wicket: hide a component without having to add all its children

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-6

I've been doing a project in Wicket, and I often find myself in an annoying situation. Let's say I have a piece of  markup that I only show when some condition applies, like the following example:

```
<div wicket:id="myContainer">
    <div wicket:id="label1"></div>
    <div wicket:id="label2"></div>
    <div wicket:id="label3"></div>
    <div wicket:id="label4"></div>
</div>
```

and in my Java code:

```
WebMarkupContainer myContainer = new WebMarkupContainer("myContainer");
add(myContainer);

if(myDataObject != null){
    myContainer.add(new Label("label1", myDataObject.getData1());
    myContainer.add(new Label("label2", myDataObject.getData2());
    myContainer.add(new Label("label3", myDataObject.getData3());
    myContainer.add(new Label("label4", myDataObject.getData4());
} else{
    //HAVING TO DO THIS IS ABSURD!
   myContainer.add(new Label("label1", "");
   myContainer.add(new Label("label2", "");
   myContainer.add(new Label("label3", "");
   myContainer.add(new Label("label4", "");
   myContainer.setVisible(false);
}
```

As you can see, I'm forced to add dummy components to the container even in the cases where I'm not gonna show it, otherwise Wicket will throw an exception, saying I have components in the markup that I haven't added in code.

To me, this is ridiculous, having to instantiate extra components that I'm not gonna show is wasteful, time-consuming and makes the code less readable unnecessarily.

I'm hoping that it's just my ignorance of Wicket and that someone can tell me a method that allows me to "discard a component and all children".

Comment: @soorapadman: mmmm, that's not how Wicket works... if you don't add the components it will fail.

Comment: I know didn't meant that don't add lables  to container. I have specified to  override the `isVisible` in `WebMarkupContainer` . since cost is high i have removed my comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have time to try it right now but I'm pretty sure that

```
} else{
  myContainer.setVisible(false);
}
```

should work.
Wicket won't complain that children are missing if the parent component is not rendered at all.

Comment: Well, there was something definitely messed up with my wicket setup. After updating it to the latest version, it now works as you say: if container is not visible, it doesn't complain about non-added children (as it's logical... I did think it was strange having to add stuff that wasn't even shown!). I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 5):

You could improve you code a lot, so it becomes less painful :)

This is a nice place to use the [CompoundPropertyModel](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/guide/single.html#modelsforms%20CompoundPropertyModel).

Also, just control the visibility in the `onConfigure()` of the container.

```
WebMarkupContainer myContainer = new WebMarkupContainer("myContainer", new CompoundPropertyModel(myDataObject))
{
    public void onConfigure()
    {
        setVisible( this.getModelObject() != null);
    }
}

add(myContainer);

myContainer.add(new Label("data1"));
myContainer.add(new Label("data2"));
myContainer.add(new Label("data3"));
myContainer.add(new Label("data4"));
```

---

### Alternative

The way you use your `WebMarkupContainer` suggests you could also use a `Panel` there to build a nice display component for this "myDataObject"

**Java**

```
public class MyDataObjectPanel extends Panel
{
    public MyDataObjectPanel(String id, IModel<MyDataObject> myDataObjectModel)
    {
        super(id,  new CompoundPropertyModel(myDataObjectModel);
        this.add(new Label("data1"));
        this.add(new Label("data2"));
        this.add(new Label("data3"));
        this.add(new Label("data4"));
    }

    public void onConfigure()
    {
        setVisible( this.getModelObject() != null);
    }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<wicket:panel>
    <div wicket:id="data1"></div>
    <div wicket:id="data2"></div>
    <div wicket:id="data3"></div>
    <div wicket:id="data4"></div>
</wicket:panel>
```

Then all places where you want to display it, just use this panel.

---

I would *advise against this* (because it makes you code more complicated and I don't think you'll win a lot of performance), but if you really care for not adding elements to the wicket-component-tree, you could the next code. It decides whether to display the specialized component or not and *replaces* the actual component:

```
public class MainComponent {

    @Override
    protected void onConfigure()
    {
        MyDataObject obj = getDataObjectFromSomeModel();
        if (obj == null) {
            this.addOrReplace( new EmptyPanel("dataPanelId").setVisible(false));
        }
        else {
            this.addOrReplace( new MyDataObjectPanel("dataPanelId"));   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Accepting this answer because it showed me how to this more elegantly, although it still doesn't solve my original question, since I still have to `add(new Label(...))` four times even if I don't want to display anything. i still find it absurd that I can't just discard a piece of the markup tree in a single line, it would seem a useful feature but apparently I'm missing something in their reasoning...

Comment: @Master_T you can prevent added a bigger component that will not be rendered, I added an example in the last part of my answer. If the specialised component it rather large, it might be worth it.

Comment: Sorry, but I had to un-accept your answer and accept the one from marting-g. Seems something was broken in my setup, Wicket doesn't actually require adding children of non-visible components. So my premise was wrong, and my question pointless. Gave you a +1 anyway for the explanation about models, it's appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, glad to help

Answer (score 2):

Don't assume that the cost is high.

Invisible components don't execute many methods, with the most important methods being onRender() and onComponentTag(). Models don't execute getObject(). 
The cost visible from the point of view html generation is zero.
Additional info:
https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/guide/componentLifecycle.html

My knowledge is checked against current version 7.5.0

I think Components (invisible) must exist, this is normal Wicket philosophy. Invisible Components are lightweight.

BTW I'm not sure Your myDataObject is wicket Model. 
I agree with recommendation in doc: **use models**.

Code will be cleaner without such 'if' - I prefer not using branched instantiation - but with correct model.

Avoid too much "active" code in constructor, for example don't get values, let be conditionally (lazy) fetched via Model. 
Catching exceptions thrown in Wicket constructors is ugly. But application can catch exceptions in rendering phase very well.

And in last words, remember, these are two policies to make component hidden, one static, the second dynamic:
https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/guide/keepControl.html#keepControl_1

Comment: I'm trying to move towards models, the application originally didn't use them. However... isn't that just moving the problem elsewhere? I mean, even using models I would still need to return dummy data from my model or wrap a dummy object in my model, depending on the implementation. It's weird to me that I can't just tell wicket do "discard the component and all its children", it seems like such a convenient and obvious functionality...

Comment: It's probably cheaper to construct the page only once and re-use is with a model than to re-build the page and component tree each time your data changes.  You don't discard your component tree, you just modify it slightly based on the content. You don't need dummy data. You should invest some time in reading about how Wicket works with models. The learing curve is a bit steep, but well worth it. Code becomes much nicer when you use it properly (see my answer for example ;))